# How to remove and add a view using an if statement using backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to remove my old `carView` and add the next one once the `NEXT` button is clicked.

Everything is coming out of a JSON file and is incrementing correctly but I want to view to also change.

Here's the code for my view:

```
window.CarContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#car-container'),
    template:_.template($('#tpl-car-container').html()),
    initialize:function () { 
        _.bindAll(this, 'clickNext');
        this.car_number = 0;
        this.car_model = this.model.get('carCollection').models[this.question_number];
        this.question_view = null;
    },
    render:function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template()); 
        this.car_view = new CarView({el: $(this.el).find('#car'), model: this.car_model});
        this.question_view.render();
        $('#next').bind('click', this.clickNext);        
        return this;
    },
    createNewCar: function () {
        //build
        console.log('createNewCar');
        if(condition) {
            //if the next button is pressed, clear screen and add new screen
        }
    },
    clickNext: function () {
        this.car_number++;
        console.log(this.car_number);
        createNewCar();
    }, 
    clickPrevious: function () { 

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Comments explain the changes.  Basically, create a new CarView each time. And don't pass in the `el` to the view, else when you call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) that element will be gone.  Instead, render the new view into `#car` each time.

```
window.CarContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#car-container'),
    template:_.template($('#tpl-car-container').html()),
    // use events hash instead of directly using jquery.
    events: {
        'click #next': 'clickNext'
    },
    initialize:function () { 
        // no need to use bindAll since using events hash
        // binds the context of clickNext to this view already.
        this.car_number = 0;
    },
    render:function () {
        // use this.$el instead.
        this.$el.html(this.template()); 
        this.createNewCar();      
        return this;
    },
    createNewCar: function () {
        if(this.car_view){
            // cleanup old view.
            this.car_view.remove();
        }
        // do some bounds checking here, or in clickNext... or both!
        var car_model = this.model.get('carCollection').models[this.car_number];

        // create a new view for the new car.
        this.car_view = new CarView({model: car_model});

        // render into #car instead of passing `el` into the view.
        // let Backbone generate a div for the view, you dont need to 
        // set an `el` in the CarView either.
        this.$('#car').html(this.car_view.render().el);
    },
    clickNext: function () {
        this.car_number++;
        this.createNewCar();
    }, 
    clickPrevious: function () { 

    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that I keep getting this error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.question_view.render')

Comment: Thanks! @Paul Hoenecke The only problem is that I keep getting this error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.question_view.render')

Comment: @user2238696 Well... you never set `this.question_view` to anything. I just left it in there since it was in your original post.  Just remove it if you don't need it. Updated answer.

Comment: this.question_view is supposed to be this.car_view. It was an type error when i was simplifying my naming conventions

Comment: @user2238696 So is there a problem still? I removed `question_view` from the answer.